# system clock synchronized: no

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, synchronization, chrony

`# timedatectl` reports `System clock synchronized: no` even when `NTP service: active` and `# systemctl status chronyd` shows `active (running)`, and the logs therein don't show anything like an error; I see for example "Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data".  This is a RHEL 8 system, the /etc/chrony.conf file is the default.

I expected to see `System clock synchronized: yes`, which I think means the system is getting synchronized with the pool specified in /etc/chrony.conf.  Maybe I'm missing something misinterpreting what this means?

Edit: Full `# timedatectl` output

```
               Local time: Tue 2020-10-06 12:11:32 PDT
           Universal time: Tue 2020-10-06 19:11:32 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-10-06 19:11:32
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Edit: Answer is in https://serverfault.com/questions/1036676/system-clock-synchronized-no-flip-it-to-yes

Comment: Can you post the entire results of `timedatectl`? Add to your question, please.

Comment: curiously, the time is right; it matches what I read when I google the time in the PDT timezone.

Comment: Mine shows **yes**, but I'm using `systemd-timesyncd` instead of `ntp`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same behaviour.
to solve it, run the follow command as root:

**hwclock --systohc**

This will synchronize your hardware clock with your system time to make it more precise

Comment: Although this might be obvious for you, I need to says that this command should NOT be run on a VM :)

Comment: oh! I almost did just that. What should I do in a VM?